# Removing a value from a cookie with Jquery and cookie.split

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have created the following script which loops over my cookie. When I find a match I want to remove just the matching value from the cookie. How do I achieve this?

```
 var cookieName = 'myCookie';
 var cookie = $.cookie("preferences");
 var cookie = cookie.split('|');

 $(cookie).each(function(index){
      var thisCookieData = this.split(',');
      if(thisCookieData[0] == thisWidget.id ){
           alert("Match!");
      }
      alert(thisCookieData);
 });
```

Comment: I am not sure whether you want the entire portion of `cookie` (caused by the first `split`) removed if a match is within, or just a part of the chunk which resulted from the second `split`. Regardless, using "magic string" formats is not recommended. I would use a serialization scheme such as JSON to store my structure. There are JS cookie libraries which have JSON and jQuery support built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

    `cookie = $.grep(cookie, function(item, index) {
        var parts = item.split(',');
        return parts[0] !== id;
    }).join('|');`

grep is a jquery function which finds elements in an array which satisfies the given function.

Answer (score 0):

split, remove and join again:

```
.split(',')
...
.join(',')
```